# How to set the Text of a ScrollingMovementMethod onClick to the top

Tags: android, scroll, onclick, textview, onclicklistener

I have a `ScrollingMovementMethod` with a `TextView`:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:maxLines="5"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

I want that if I scroll the text of my TextView down, I can jump to the top of the text if I click a button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text is the TextView.
This comes into the onClick:

```
text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
text.scrollTo(0, 0)
```